# How to filter .mp3 files using Amazon S3 listObjects

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 service with node.js and I want to filter all .mp3 files in a directory, using Amazon S3 `listObjects()`. There is a `prefix` parameter but there is no `sufix`. Is there any way to do that using a regular expression or a filter like *.mp3 or something?

This is the function reference http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property

```
var prefix = "myS3dir/";
bucket.listObjects({Prefix:prefix}, function(err, data){
    //do something with data
});
```

Comment: You probably want to iterate over the keys and yes, use a regular expression.

Comment: Yes, that's one solution, but I don't want to iterate over the keys, I want listObjects to return the filtered key list. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible with S3. You can only filter by prefix server-side. This has to do with the fact that S3 does not have a true key hierarchy, it's mostly a key object store, and prefix matching works there.

If you want to do suffix matching you basically have to pull out the name of all the keys and inspect them client-side.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to query by .mp3 file extension and the number of S3 objects is small then just enumerate all S3 objects and provide your own in-memory filter/query. If the number of S3 objects is huge (like 10k+ which would be slow to enumerate) then you need a different solution. Assuming that you do not directly expose the S3 structure to end-users, then here are a few ideas:

1. Insert a prefix ahead of the filename, for example
   mybucket/mp3/beatit.mp3 - then you can use prefix: mybucket/mp3/. Note: this is no good if you also want to query "beat*", for example.
2. Reverse the filename, for example 3pm.titaeb, and search for prefix mybucket/3pm. I know that sounds
   weird and it would prevent a query for "beat*" but in some situations it is a good solution.
3. Use a secondary database, for example MySQL, that is indexed on file extension, and anything else you need, and that contains references to the S3 locations.